# How can I block screen shots and records only for third apps

Tags: reactjs, electron

How I can restrict sreenshots and records only of third apps?

My app needs record screen for audit activity but with setContentProtection the recording don't show the content of my app. Can I add my app id to a "whitelist" for allow this function?

I've searched about  NSWindowSharing on mac, and found is possible differentiate between apps for this permission but i don't found this config on electron

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/testing-widevine-cdm